# An unknown function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I run into a function: $1_{[-n, n]^r}$. I guess this function equals 1 whenever x falls into $[-n, n]^r$. Am I right?

I met this function in an analysis paper which deals with measure and density of $L^p$ space.

Comment: Yes, and it is $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker That could be an answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct: It likely refers to an [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), also called a characteristic function. Other common notation is $\chi_A$, referring to the function that is $1$ for all $x \in A$, and $0$ for all $x \notin A$.